# Android : How the images can be saved and retrieved efficiently from server side?

Tags: android, spring, image, couchbase

I'm creating a native android application which loads images of users. (An image of the user that is shown as in WhatsApp, messenger, etc). I need to update the image once a user changes it.

One approach I'm aware of is saving images on a separate server and saving the link to the image in the database. While loading, fetch the image from the specified url and cache it.

Another is saving the image as blob (don't think it's efficient) and cache it.

What are the approaches that I have to save images and retrieve them efficiently?

I'm using spring boot and couchbase as backend

Comment: Are you using Couchbase Lite to sync?

Comment: Still no. But yes, I can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save a link:

- Often you can store the image on a cloud server that's less expensive
- You have to retrieve the link, then build the code to retrieve the image
- Checking for updates is at least slightly more complicated

If you use Couchbase Lite:

- New images can propagate easily to the client
- Storage is efficient

  - Blobs are stored as separate files
  - The associated document overhead is tiny
- Simple to implement

Comment: What is the method you propose to save and retrieve new images that I need to  propagate to the client?

Comment: I'm not sure from you description what the exact flow is supposed to be (meaning, where does the user upload a new image and where does it need to go).  But the general idea would be to simply have the app that receives the new image update a document with an attachment.  The apps that need to receive the new image run replications.  The image doc gets pulled down automatically.  Look at the CB docs and ask on the forums for more help.